# How to build Flutter Engine into Static Library from source code

Tags: flutter, ninja, flutter-engine

Flutter Engine is now build into Dynamic Library though ninja, what if I want to build into Static Library??? How to modify the BUILD.gn file???

My build commnd is:

```
flutter/tools/gn --ios --runtime-mode release
ninja -C out/ios_release -t clean
ninja -C out/ios_release -j 8
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.